# How to create a date object from a date-string which contains AM/PM?

Tags: javascript, date

Is there any way to define a javascript date object with AM/PM value?

Something like this

```
var startDate = new Date("1900-1-1 8:20:00 PM");
```

Comment: @pablochan I get "invalid date"...

Comment: @pablochan Nope, it doesn't return me proper value when I try to call startDate.getHours(), it returns NaN, while when I define date like this var startTime = new Date(1900,1,1,8,20,0); call to getHours() properly returns 8 :(

Comment: @Bakudan-ханювиги—no, it will not. Date.parse is very browser dependent. To reliably convert a string to a date object, it must be parsed manually.

Comment: @PawanNogariya A `8PM` time should return 20, not 8.

Comment: @PawanNogariya: It works in Chrome but apparently not everywhere. Check my answer.

Comment: @PawanNogariya—you realise that `new Date(1900,1,1)` is 1 February 1900? Months are zero indexed.

Comment: @RobG - Actually I am not concerned about date part here as I only need time part, so I just want to provide a fake date, however Sime Vidas answer worked for me.

Comment: @pablochan - Thanks! However Sime Vidas approach worked for me in all the browser

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works:

```
new Date( '1 Jan 1900 8:20:00 PM' )
```

and is equivalent to

```
new Date( '1 Jan 1900 20:20:00' )
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cVE2E/

Answer (score 0):

you can use Date.parse

```
var startDate = new Date(Date.parse("1900-1-1 8:20:00 PM"));
```

Comment: `new Date` is able to parse date-strings.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas—but not consistently across browsers, and Date.parse isn't much better.

Comment: @RobG From my understanding, `new Date` and `Date.parse` process date-strings equivalently. Therefore `new Date( Date.parse( ... ) )` is an anti-pattern (analogous to `new String ( String( ... ) )`). That's what I was pointing out in my comment...

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that browsers do not parse date strings consistently. No browser I've tested parses dates according to  ES5 section 15.9.1.15 (I haven't tested exhaustively). So the fact that a few common browsers happen to parse a particular (non-standard) format consistently should not be accepted as proof that all browsers will do so, now or in the future.

Comment: @RobG I understand that. I was replying to the second part of your comment where you say that Date.parse "isn't much better". `new Date` and `Date.parse` parse date-strings in the exact same manner, so one can obviously not be any better than the other.

Comment: Yes, a string supplied to `new Date()` should be parsed as for `Date.parse()`, so I should have said "is no better".

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the browser and/or the locale. But I found a script that can help: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the Date.parse() method, and hence the new Date() constructor can parse any specific date format. By the ECMAScript standard, only a specific ISO 8601 format and some implementation-dependent formats need to be processed.

Thus, for portability at least, you need to use other tools, such as the [Globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) library; using it, you would use

```
Globalize.parseDate('1900-1-1 8:20:00 PM','yyyy-M-d h:mm:ss tt')
```

which returns a Date object when the first argument matches the format specified by the second argument.

If you need to process *alternative* date formats on input, you may need to write code that tries reading the data using specific formats until it gets a non-null result.