# Concatenate date and time string into mongo date object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am sending two fields from client side `date` and `time`.

`date` will be in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` i.e 2016-11-08 and `time` will be in the format of `05:30 PM` or `09:45 AM`.

I want to combine these two fields and create new field say `added_datetime` , this field going to be inserted inside `MongoDB`, so I want it to be in the form of `Mongo Date Object` so that I can use it for searching with date.

Tried some random things using `moments.js` but unable to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [a similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624483/how-to-create-a-date-object-from-a-date-string-which-contains-am-pm) you can create a date object with

```
var date = new Date(datestring);
```

The code

```
var startDate = new Date("1900-1-1 8:20:00 PM");
```

which the original questioner supplied works in chrome and should also work in node since it's the same js engine. This seems to answer your question.

You can find more on dates in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [MongoDB documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)